# how to webscrape the "key statistics" from morningstar.com to python and pandas

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping

so the link of the data i want to webscrape is this one
https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xidx/smsm/valuation

and the data i want to scrape is this one down bellow

[THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CFYB.png)

Pleaseee help mee :(

i would like to have the table in my jupyter notebook so i can use pandas and python to do my stock and investing analysis

Comment: The page you want to request uses an api key. If you manage to get that api key, you can get the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page loads the data through an API endpoint that requires the API key if accessed directly. But you can simulate the request sent by the browser to get the same data in python.
Use inspector to find out the exact request, copy the CURL request and convert it to python using [online tool](https://curlconverter.com/python/)
Here is the converted request. You can get the results in json with `response.json`

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'api-global.morningstar.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'apikey': 'lstzFDEOhfFNMLikKa0am9mgEKLBl49T',
    'origin': 'https://www.morningstar.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xidx/smsm/valuation',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-api-realtime-e': 'eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.X-h4zn65XpjG8cZnL3e6hj8LMbzupQBglHZce7tzu-c4utCtXQ2IYoLxdik04usYRhNo74AS_2crdjLnBc_J0lFEdAPzb_OBE7HjwfRaYeNhfXIDw74QCrFGqQ5n7AtllL-vTGnqmI1S9WJhSwnIBe_yRxuXGGbIttizI5FItYY.bB3WkiuoS1xzw78w.iTqTFVbxKo4NQQsNNlbkF4tg4GCfgqdRdQXN8zQU3QYhbHc-XDusH1jFii3-_-AIsqpHaP7ilG9aBxzoK7KPPfK3apcoMS6fDM3QLRSZzjkBoxWK75FtrQMAN5-LecdJk97xaXEciS0QqqBqNugoSPwoiZMazHX3rr7L5jPM-ecXN2uEjbSR0wfg-57iHAku8jvThz4mtGpMRAOil9iZaL6iRQ.o6tR6kuOQBhnpcsdTQeZWw',
    'x-api-requestid': 'cdbb5a73-9654-4b31-a845-32844eb44ca8',
    'x-sal-contenttype': 'e7FDDltrTy+tA2HnLovvGL0LFMwT+KkEptGju5wXVTU=',
}

params = {
    'languageId': 'en',
    'locale': 'en',
    'clientId': 'MDC',
    'component': 'sal-components-valuation',
    'version': '3.79.0',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://api-global.morningstar.com/sal-service/v1/stock/valuation/v3/0P0000BPTU',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
)
```